# FullHttpRequest.uri() doesn't return values after `#`

Tags: java, netty

I have a problem with parsing the callback which I should received. Example callback request
`https://localhost:443/api/callback#code=DUMMY_CODE` and as a result after it's handled by Netty I get uri `https://localhost:443/api/callback`. Is there any possible solution to allow Netty to bypass raw URI without any transformation in the meantime?

Comment: Everything after the `#` is an anchor and isn't available on the server as it isn't part of the URL.

Comment: alright, but is there any feasible solution to bypass anchor's values to the server?

Comment: No. As those are simply not send by your browser or client a per HTTP specification.